# Encode a column where values based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to encode a column where the value is based on another column, not 0-1.

For example, my original table is as follows:

`+-------+-------+-------+
| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 | A     |     1 |
|     1 | B     |     2 |
|     1 | E     |     3 |
|     2 | C     |     4 |
|     2 | D     |     5 |
|     3 | A     |     6 |
|     3 | B     |     7 |
|     3 | D     |     8 |
|     3 | E     |     9 |
+-------+-------+-------+`

The expected output is

`+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Col 1 | Col2_A | Col2_B | Col2_C | Col2_D | Col2_E |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     1 |      1 |      2 |      0 |      0 |      3 |
|     2 |      0 |      0 |      4 |      5 |      0 |
|     3 |      6 |      7 |      0 |      8 |      9 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+`

I could not figure out how to solve it using pandas.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is relatively straightforward. Lets assume your `DataFrame` is `df`, and you have a column `Foo` where `Foo = Bar * 2`. Your code would then be `df['Foo'] = df['Bar'].apply(lambda x: x*2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple pivot i.e

```
df.pivot('Col 1','Col 2','Col 3').fillna(0)
```

```
Col 2   A        B        C        D        E     
Col 1                                             
1          1.0      2.0      0.0      0.0      3.0
2          0.0      0.0      4.0      5.0      0.0
3          6.0      7.0      0.0      8.0      9.0
```

For your desired output, update provided by @pir using pivot_table

```
df.pivot_table('Col 3', 'Col 1', 'Col 2', fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, 1).add_prefix('Col2_').reset_index()
```

Or using pivot

```
df.pivot('Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3').fillna(0).rename_axis(None, 1).add_prefix('Col2_').reset_index()
```

```
   Col 1  Col2_ A  Col2_ B   Col2_ C  Col2_ D   Col2_ E     
0      1    1.0    2.0      0.0      0.0           3.0
1      2    0.0    0.0      4.0      5.0           0.0
2      3    6.0     7.0     0.0      8.0           9.0
```

Comment: You can use `pivot_table` and utilize its `fill_value` argument `df.pivot_table('Col 3', 'Col 1', 'Col 2', fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, 1).add_prefix('Col2_').reset_index()`

Answer (score 2):

Using `set_index` and `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['Col 1', 'Col 2'])['Col 3'].unstack(fill_value=0)

Col 2  A  B  C  D  E
Col 1               
1      1  2  0  0  3
2      0  0  4  5  0
3      6  7  0  8  9
```

Or add a few more bits to replicate OP's exact expected output

```
df.set_index(['Col 1', 'Col 2'])['Col 3'].unstack(fill_value=0) \
  .rename_axis(None, 1).add_prefix('Col2_').reset_index()

   Col 1  Col2_A  Col2_B  Col2_C  Col2_D  Col2_E
0      1       1       2       0       0       3
1      2       0       0       4       5       0
2      3       6       7       0       8       9
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the 3rd time I using `crosstab` today ..

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['Col 1'],columns=df['Col 2'],values=df['Col 3'],aggfunc=sum).\
      fillna(0).rename_axis(None, 1).add_prefix('Col2_').reset_index()
```